# Unable use Quality Gates

Tags: sonarqube5.6

I defined Quality Gate and already seeing the project violating threshold but it does not show any error/warning message.

Please refer attached screenshot which shows Quality Gate I set for project but at the top says "You should define a quality gate on this project."

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be the case when you have first defined a quality gate but not run any scans using it. Once you have run your first scan you should see the Quality gate summary at the top as expected.